# Uploading images using angularjs and php

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, upload

I have a websites code to edit and i have there a issue i can't solve on my own. I hope you can help me ;)

I have a HTML form with a few input fields, the form uses angularJS and on buttenpress, the data is commited via control to a php file, were a xml is made out of it.
I want to add a imageupload to the process, but i'm new to angular and couldn't find anything helpful in the web.

Here are my files:

HTML:

```
  <input type="file" file-upload multiple/>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="file in renderData.images">{{file.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

controlers.js

```
   $scope.$on("fileSelected", function (event, args) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {            
        //add the file object to the scope's files collection
        $scope.renderData.images.push(args.file);
    });
});
```

> 

```
myApp.directive('fileUpload', function () {
return {
    scope: true,        //create a new scope
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            //iterate files since 'multiple' may be specified on the element
            for (var i = 0;i<files.length;i++) {
                //emit event upward
                scope.$emit("fileSelected", { file: files[i] });
            }                                       
        });
    }
}; });
```

> 

```
                $scope.url = 'rest/video.php';
            $http.post($scope.url, { "data": $scope.renderData}).

                success(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.status = status;
                    $scope.result = data;
                    console.log($scope.result.timeStamp);
                    var timestamp = $scope.result.timeStamp;
                    if(!$scope.result.error) {
                        $scope.userDataValid = true;
                        $scope.renderProcess = true;
                        if($scope.renderProcess) {
                            $scope.interval = $interval(function() {
                                $scope.getVideo(parseInt(timestamp));
                            }, 40000);
                        }
                    }
                }).

                error(function(data, status) {
                    $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
                    $scope.status = status;
                });
        }
```

video.php

```
function readInput() {
    $validate = array();
    $validate['error'] = true;

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $objData = json_decode($data);

    // validate input
    foreach($objData->data as $key => $value) {
        // check images
        if($key === 'images') {
            foreach($value as $image) {
```

And here is the point I don't know how to handle the data in php and save the file to the server.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You might want to remove the angular tag. If the file data is arriving correctly at your server, then this is a pure php question

Comment: sorry, i don't understand that. i want to use angular, to submit the form and upload the file without leaveing the page.